# How to find N longest lines in a text file

Tags: java

Write a program to read a multiple line text file and write the 'N' longest lines to stdout.

There was a similar question but I didn't really understand it since it involves using a min-heap and that would create more work since I'd have to create a min-heap data structure.

I tried to create an array that size n. Then sort it but I would have to sort it each and every time I inserted a new line into the array. I'd like to know what's the simple approach and what would be the optimal one.

Comment: what happened if there are multiple lines of the same length ??

Comment: Let's just say it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why would you have to resort the array after every line?  Easiest: read the whole file into an array/list, sort once based on length, then print the first N entries.  Optimal: see answer by James Black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of N strings.

Loop through the file.

If the number of items in the array is < N then just add it to the end.

In all cases store the shortest length of the line in the array.
If the array is full, then compare to the shortest line, if the new line is > then that line, replace, and find the shortest line.

Repeat loop.

Print strings.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that I could avoid a O(N^3) but looks like it's not possible if I want to do it the easy way

Comment: You can keep the amount of extra looping to a minimum. For example if you store the shortest length and the location of that line in the array, then when you replace you will need to just replace that line. You can also store the length of each string in a separate array so you can loop and find the next smallest loop, as looping through N arrays should be fairly quick.  You will end up having to trade memory for speed if you want more optimizations, but the best bet is to profile and see where it is slow before doing any optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As other mentionned my first solution would not work for lines of the same length. A better approach would then be to use a `java.util.PriorityQueue<Line>` and define an object Line like this:

```
class Line {
  private final String line;
  public Line(String line) {
    this.line = line;
  }

  public int getLen() {
    return line.length();
  }

  public String getLine() {
    return line;
  }
}
```

You then instanciate a `PriorityQueue` and specify the order using a `Comparator`.

[`PriorityQueue<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):
`PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`

> Creates a PriorityQueue with the
>   specified initial capacity that orders
>   its elements according to the
>   specified comparator.

Here is an experimentation using a unit test.

```
        int n = 1;
        PriorityQueue<Line> queue = new PriorityQueue<Line>(n, new Comparator<Line>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Line a, Line b) {
                return a.getLen() - b.getLen();
            }
        });

        queue.add(new Line("abcd"));
        queue.add(new Line("abcde"));
        queue.add(new Line("abc"));

        assertEquals(queue.poll().getLine(), "abc");
        assertEquals(queue.poll().getLine(), "abcd");
        assertEquals(queue.poll().getLine(), "abcde");
```

In this example we see that poll remove remove first the smallest element of the list. You could simply call `queue.poll()` if `queue.size() > n` after each line insertion.

Comment: what happens when two lines are the same length?

Comment: @akf Good point. I think my solution is not that good then. It should instead use some kind of SortedBiList.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

the reason of using a treemap is to handle the multiple lines with same length, in this case, all of the lines will be added into the same ArrayList

```
public class DataCollector {

    private int size;
    private TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> data = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    public DataCollector(int nthLargest) {

        if (nthLargest < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("can not be smaller than 1");
        }

        this.size = nthLargest;
    }

    public void feed(String line) {

        int length = line.length();

        if (data.size() > 0 && length < data.firstKey()) {
            return;
        }

        getList(length).add(line);



        if (data.size() > size) {
            data.remove(data.firstKey());
        }
    }

    private List<String> getList(int key) {
        if (!data.containsKey(key)) {
            data.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        return data.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            builder.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue()).append("\r\n");
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public List<String> getResult() {


        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

        return data.firstEntry().getValue();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DataCollector co = new DataCollector(1);


        co.feed("b");
        co.feed("abc");
        co.feed("abc1");
        co.feed("abc2");
        co.feed("abc33");
        co.feed("abc34");
        co.feed("abc23");
        co.feed("abc23b");
        co.feed("abc23b");
        co.feed("abc23c");
        co.feed("abc23dd");
        co.feed("abc23ee");
        co.feed("a");

        System.out.println(co);
        System.out.println(co.getResult());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that multiple lines of the same length are not allowed. Here's the algo:

1. Create a sorted dictionary with key => length of the string and value => line.
2. Print the last N lines of the dictionary.

If multiple lines of the same length are allowed then Dictionary has to be modified to include List as value.
Here's the code:

SortedDictionary> processed = new SortedDictionary>();

```
        int N;
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(args[0]);

        N = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                continue;

            line.Trim();

            if (processed.ContainsKey(line.Length))
            {
                processed[line.Length].Add(line);
            }
            else
            {
                processed.Add(line.Length, new List<string> { line });
            }
        }
        while(N != 0)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> kvp in processed.Reverse())
            {
                kvp.Value.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c));
                if (--N == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
```